# c# objects won't go under each other

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

i'm making a simple login-register program, i save usernames and passwords in lists.

i'm trying to show all the usernames under each other and that it wil repeat everytime a new user will be registered.

for some reason it only shows the last user, and that's it.

```
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < frmLogin.reg_usernames.Count; i++ )
        {
             TextBox lbl =  new TextBox { Location = new Point(15, 30), BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D, BackColor = Color.AliceBlue, Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.Name, 9), ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical };

            this.Controls.Add(lbl);

            lbl.Text = frmLogin.reg_usernames[i];

        }
```

Comment: You're putting all the textboxes at the same position, so they're all in the same place... so only the last one is visible. You need to adjust the position for each new TextBox you add.

Comment: Looks to me like they should all go *on top of each other* since you give them the same `Location`. Try giving them *different* locations.

Comment: Please revise your tags. You probably need to indicate a UI toolkit that you are working with. At the same time, the *object* tag is irrelevant here; almost every question on C# is *somehow* using objects.

Comment: Try `lbl.text += frmLogin.reg_usernames[i].Text`  and put a <br/> in there somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the boxes down as you go:

```
  TextBox lbl = new TextBox { Location = new Point(15, 30 * i), BorderStyle ....
```

Note that your form would need to be large enough to see them all, as well.  You may need to set your height appropriately, or place the text boxes inside of a container which could scroll, instead of directly on the form itself.